# How to modify Fancybox 1.3.4 CSS to implement custom controls?

Tags: html, css, fancybox

How to modify Fancybox 1.3.4 CSS in order to implement custom controls image?
The css and image below:

[controls](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/4081/controlsj.png)

[CSS](http://demo-store.prestashop.com/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css)

Comment: So, you just want other images as forwards, backwards buttons?

Comment: Yes, I want use these buttons, forward, back and close.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the image sprite with a custom one, top three icons are forwards, backward and close, the bottom ones are the same if hovered.